# How to retrieve all rows between two dates in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a question and hope for an answer.

now i want to retrieve some data from the database based on specific date.

So i have a table in the database called flights. this table stores the some air flights data in it.

I wrote a simple code to retrieve the flights through an interval:
say i want to get the flights from day 24/11/2015 to 3/12/2015.

but the problem is when get the new month, the program crashes. i used a for loop so it keeps retrieving data forever.

how to increment date in php?

here is my code:

```
<?php

for($i = $date1; $i <= $date2; $i++)
{
$sql3 = "select * from flights where flight_date = '$i'";

$query3 = mysql_query($sql3);

$numrows3 = mysql_num_rows($query3);

if($numrows3 > 0)
{
 // retrieve flights.
}
} // end of for loop

?>
```

Comment: It would be far more efficient to let MySQL get all the rows you need rather than issue multiple queries, e.g. `select * from flights where flight_date between '2015-11-24' and '2015-12-03'`

Comment: And then you can get rid of the pesky `for` loop as well. ++2 for this approach.

Comment: server not loving on you when you do it this way

Comment: Please also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @PaulDixon thanks very much bro, it works. please write it in answer to accept it as solution for my question :)

Comment: @Drew yes, it almost make server to down, but fortunately this is offline server so i just test this on it.

Comment: Done :) I've also changed the title of your question, as the original wouldn't help anyone searching for this in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be far more efficient to let MySQL get all the rows you need rather than issue multiple queries, e.g.

```
select * from flights where flight_date between '2015-11-24' and '2015-12-03'
```

Just be sure to format the dates in your query correctly (yyyy-mm-dd). Also, please avoid mysql_ functions, [they will be disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)!

Comment: thank you so much, glad to help me :)... please vote up for question so no needs to get vote down as it is not an ambigious quesiton.